# How to display the list of available languages with sphinx?

Tags: python, internationalization, python-sphinx

Having generated and translated catalogs of text following the [i18n sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html), what is needed to automatically display a list of available localisations, like there is on the header of the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)?

Is this even possible? Is the python languages list generated in a process that does not involve sphinx?

Comment: The first link doesn't work

Comment: You'll have to inspect the sources in the Python repository to figure it out. The dropdown list is generated by JavaScript code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/tools/static/switchers.js#L44

Answer (score 0):

The supported languages are listed on the source:

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/master/sphinx/locale

Comment: Ok but how does it helps to display the same dropdown menu as the python documentation has on its header?